# Figuring out big O'notation of a naive depth-first-search scheduling algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, asymptotics, trees

(I'm not sure if this question belongs here, but stack overflow doesn't work with LaTeX so here it is)

An inefficient solution to a scheduling problem similar to the [2018 Google Hashcode](https://storage.googleapis.com/coding-competitions.appspot.com/HC/2018/hashcode2018_qualification_task.pdf) problem (unless you already know of this problem I wouldn't recommend reading it for this, it will likely overcomplicated this).

Given $n$ tasks and $m$ agents and that 1 agent can do 1 task at a time, you want to assign agents to tasks such that all tasks are completed in the minimum amount of time.

An extremely expensive algorithm is an application of depth-first-search, constructing a tree of every possible assignment and from that finding the shortest path (minimum time required).

Considering a problem with 2 agents and 3 tasks, for each node in each layer you have so many outgoing edges (considering at layer $i$ there are $n+1-i$ tasks remaining):

1. $mn = 2 \cdot 3 = 6$
2. $m(n-1)=2 \cdot 2 = 4$
3. $m(n-2)=2 \cdot 1 = 2$

As such the number of outgoing edges you have in each layer are:

1. $mn=\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}m^1=2 \cdot 3 = 6$
2. $mn\cdot m(n-1)=\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}m^2=(2 \cdot 3)(2 \cdot 2) = 24$
3. $mn\cdot m(n-1)\cdot m(n-2)=\frac{n!}{(n-3)!}m^3=(2 \cdot 3)(2 \cdot 2)(2 \cdot 1) = 48$

Therefore one could give the total number of edges in the network as $t$ where:

$t=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{(n-i)!}m^i$

At this point I am stuck and do not know how I could simplify it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$t_{m,n}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{(n-i)!}m^i=e^{\frac{1}{m}}\, m^n\, \Gamma \left(n+1,\frac{1}{m}\right)-1$$ where appears the incompleta gamma function.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
m & n & t_{m,n} \\
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 4 \\
 1 & 3 & 15 \\
 1 & 4 & 64 \\
 1 & 5 & 325\\
 2 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 2 & 12 \\
 2 & 3 & 78 \\
 2 & 4 & 632 \\
 2 & 5 & 6330\\
 3 & 1 & 3 \\
 3 & 2 & 24 \\
 3 & 3 & 225 \\
 3 & 4 & 2712 \\
 3 & 5 & 40695 \\
 4 & 1 & 4 \\
 4 & 2 & 40 \\
 4 & 3 & 492 \\
 4 & 4 & 7888 \\
 4 & 5 & 157780 \\
 5 & 1 & 5 \\
 5 & 2 & 60 \\
 5 & 3 & 915 \\
 5 & 4 & 18320 \\
 5 & 5 & 458025
\end{array}
\right)$$